# google analytics for site with several domain names

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-analytics, cross-domain

I developed a wordpress with has several domain names.

It's possible to do a cross domain tracking (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en-GB&ref_topic=2772342).

I was wondering if I can place the tracking code at the top of my script.js file and as it's the same site if I can do something like:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

if(window.location.href.indexOf(".net") > -1) {
    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-Y', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
    ga('require', 'linker');
    ga('linker:autoLink', ['domainNameZ.com'] );
} else {
    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-Z', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
    ga('require', 'linker');
    ga('linker:autoLink', ['domainNameY.net'] );
}
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Thank you for your help,
q

Comment: I don't see why not, have you tried it?

Comment: yes, I'm testing it atm. It seems to work, although that I do not have them grouped in Google Analytics. Maybe I set up something wrong over there.